# node-soap working differently with different wsdl files. I am getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'postProcess' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, wsdl, node-soap

I am using node-soap to create a soap client. I have tried with different WSDL files and worked fine but one WSDL file seems complex. I tested this WSDL with SOAPUI and worked fine. But if I try to create a soap client, it is throwing the following error. Any help really appreciated!!!

***TypeError: Cannot read property 'postProcess' of undefined***

I am sharing the link to the WSDL file.

[WSDL link](https://github.com/linc96pm/WSDL-example)

Full-stack trace of error

```
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'postProcess' of undefined
      at OperationElement.postProcess (D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\elements.ts:874:15)
      at PortTypeElement.postProcess (D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\elements.ts:914:13)
      at BindingElement.postProcess (D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\elements.ts:968:16)
      at ServiceElement.postProcess (D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\elements.ts:1042:19)
      at D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\index.ts:112:30
      at WSDL._processNextInclude (D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\index.ts:1186:14)
      at WSDL.processIncludes (D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\index.ts:173:10)
      at D:\MY_PROJECTS\NODE-SOAP\node-soap-ts\node_modules\soap\src\wsdl\index.ts:101:12
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)*
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of the WSDL files. I would like to add something here. Try to add the extension `Wizdler` which is available in chrome. Once you try to open the code in chrome and run the extension, you can easily find out the data model and the methods used in the WSDL file. So, with your WSDL file, this is what I got as the result in Wizdler.

[image: Wizdler response]

This might be helpful to resolve your issue.